# How can i get responseText with Polymer is-ajax submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, submit, polymer, responsetext

After submited "ajax-form", I can not get the responseText from java HttpServlet to Javascript.

HTML Code:

```
<form is="ajax-form" action ="URL" id="formID" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ....
</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
this.$.upload.submit();
```

Servlet Code:

```
response.getWriter().append("responseText ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, the XMLHttpRequest object is available in the `submitted` event:

http://ajax-form.raynicholus.com/components/ajax-form/#ajax-form.events.submitted

So you could handle that something like this:

```
handleResponse: function(event) {
  this.response = event.detail.responseText;
  // do whatever you need to do with it.
}
```

If you're using this inside a Polymer element, you can use declarative event mapping like this:

```
<form is="ajax-form" on-submitted="{{handleResponse}} action="URL" 
    id="formID" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 ...
</form>
```

Or you can add the listener imperatively:

```
this.$.formID.addEventListener('submitted', handleResponse);
```

Hope this helps.